# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.Not sure may be a dependency issue between httpclient and httpmime

Tags: android, build.gradle

In Android Studio I am getting the following errors:-
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug :app:dexDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple
>   dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;     at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)    at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>   >     C:\Users\Priyatosh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
>   >     --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Priyatosh\Desktop\Camerafileupload27\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
>   >     --input-list=C:\Users\Priyatosh\Desktop\Camerafileupload27\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   >     Error Code:   2 Output:       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   >     com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   >     Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;      at
>   >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)         at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>   >       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)      at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)      at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)         at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

My build.gradle file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.camerafileupload"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    //compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    //compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    //compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    //compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6"

    }
```

[image]

Can anybody suggest me how to solve it.... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `build.gradle` contains `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` this library depends on 
on the v4 Support Library. So it will be added by gradle. Also you have `android-support-v4.jar` at your `libs` folder and line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`, as result AS will try to build it with 2 instances of same library.

Sulution is to remove `android-support-v4.jar` from `libs` folder and rebuild project.

**Update:**

Add into `build.gradle` next block

```
android{
....
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, After changing as suggested, I got the following errors Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
 File 1: C:\Users\Priyatosh\Desktop\Camerafileupload27\app\libs\httpcore-4.3.3.jar
 File 2: C:\Users\Priyatosh\Desktop\Camerafileupload27\app\libs\httpcore-4.3.3.jar
 added  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    } in build.gradle file, but it does not helped